# Make API request for each array element based on the first API response

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios

I'm currently learning how to work with async/await in React JS with hooks. I'm trying to make two API calls to `https://restcountries.eu/`. The firs call needs to get information about chosen country's borders. Output is ["CAN", "MEX"]. However, I need to get full names of these borders. That's why I want to make the second call. Since I have an array with two items, I need to make a new API call for each of them. I have been stuck with this for a while. What is the proper way to make the second call considering that I have an array from the first call?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const App = () => {
    const [countryDetails, setCountryDetails] = useState({});
    const [borderNames, setBorderNames] = useState([]);

   //FIRST API CALL
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await axios(
                    `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/usa?fullText=true`
                );
                setCountryDetails(response.data[0]);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        };
        fetchData();
    }, []);


    //SECONS API CALL - doens't work
    useEffect(() => {
        let borderName = [];
        countryDetails.borders.forEach(async border => {
            try {
                const response = await axios(
                    `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha?codes=${border}`
                );
                borderName.push(response.data[0].name);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
     setBorderNames(borderName);
    }, [countryDetails]);

    console.log(countryDetails.borders); //Output: ["CAN", "MEX"]
    console.log(borderNames); //Output needs to be: ["Canada", "Mexico"]
 
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>App</h2>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Since you are awaiting for the first response, just send the next one using the same technique but based on the data you just received from your first call

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your structure has some minor issue, check this example you will find out:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [countryDetails, setCountryDetails] = React.useState({});
  const [borderNames, setBorderNames] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/usa?fullText=true`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setCountryDetails(data[0]))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let borderName = [];
    if (countryDetails.borders) {
      countryDetails.borders.forEach((border) =>
        fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha?codes=${border}`)
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((data) => {
            borderName.push(data[0].name);
            if (borderName.length === countryDetails.borders.length)
              setBorderNames(borderName);
          })
          .catch((err) => console.log(err))
      );
    }
  }, [countryDetails]);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{JSON.stringify(countryDetails.borders)}</p>
      <p>{JSON.stringify(borderNames)}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach would be:

```js
useEffect(() => {
   const exec = async () => {
     const borderNames = await Promise.all(countryDetails.borders.map(border => {
       return axios.get(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha?codes=${border}`
     }))

     setBorderNames(borderNames.map(({data}) => data[0].name));
   };

   exec();
}, [countryDetails]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second fetch is async and so, because you don't `await` it, the `useEffect` sets the `borderNames` as an empty array (initial value), before the response arrives.

Apart from `await`ing the response, you can just make this change inside your `try` block:

```
const response = await axios(
   `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha?codes=${border}`);

setBorderNames(prevState => prevState.push(response.data[0].name));
```